# Netsuite journal entry approval

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to customize the template of a Journal entry basic approval which routes the approval request to the supervisor of the user who creates the journal, this is set in the Initiation stage:
Workflow : Approver=Workflow : Approver : Supervisor

What I want is to set as approver all the users who have Senior Accountant role, by preventing the user who created the journal to approve his/her own journal. I think I should use the formula field but I have no idea how to set it up... Anyone who has come across this and can help?

Comment: The process you want to setup is not clear, can you give an example to explain the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite's workflow names the approver in the workflow field.  This is used as a criteria later, presumably to show/hide the approval button.

I would suggest creating a copy of the workflow to modify.  Set the original to Status = "Not Released".

In your new workflow, you'll want to modify the criteria that shows the approve/reject buttons to look at the existing user's role.  You'll also require a second criteria to check if the current user created the journal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mark! 
"Modify the criteria that shows the approve/reject buttons to look at the existing user's role": that's exactly what I need, but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark I found the way!

1. I have created the workflow from the workflow templates that
   Netsuite provides (Journal entry basic approval)
2. I edited the condition of the two actions (add button) in the state "Pending approval" in the following way:

> User Role = Administrator, Accountant And User != Workflow : Created By

This worked! Now, all the users with roles "Administrator" and "Accountant" can approve all the journals except these created by themselves: exactly what I needed.

Thank you Mark for your help!